# When does $x^3 - x^2 - 2 x + 1$ split mod $p$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials

Conjecture: the primes for which the polynomial $x^3 - x^2 - 2 x + 1$ splits mod $p$ are the primes $\equiv 1$ or $6$ mod $7$ ([OEIS sequence A045472](https://oeis.org/A045472)).  Is this correct?

Comment: You may need to include $p=7$ because $x^3 - x^2 - 2 x + 1 = (x+2)^3 \bmod 7$.

Comment: see final example in https://www.impan.pl/en/publishing-house/journals-and-series/acta-arithmetica/all/28/3/75096/representability-by-certain-norm-forms-over-algebraic-number-fields

Comment: also see page 6 in Reuschle, https://books.google.com/books?id=wt7lgfeYqMQC&pg=PR1&lpg=PR1&dq=reuschle++tafeln+complexer+primzahlen&source=bl&ots=VGZFPrfUBn&sig=MlQ667PqXaQ9rAvLWkG3_F1rwsk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiIwtSvm9TQAhUJ-2MKHXJIA_kQ6AEIODAE#v=onepage&q=reuschle%20%20tafeln%20complexer%20primzahlen&f=false

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2385221/11619).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $\alpha$ is a root of $x^3-x^2-2x+1$ (in any field) then the latter splits as $$(x-\alpha)(x-\alpha^2+\alpha+1)(x+\alpha^2-2).$$ Also if $\alpha \neq -2$ and $\beta$ is a root of $$x^2+\alpha x + 1$$ then $\beta$ is a primitive seventh root of unity. Combining all this for the field $\mathbb{F}_p$ where $p\neq 7$: If $x^3-x^2-2x+1$ has a root in $\mathbb{F}_p$ then $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$ contains a primitive seventh root of unity and so $p^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 7$. The other way around: If $p^2\equiv 1 \pmod 7$ then $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$ contains a primitive seventh root of unity $\beta$ and $\alpha = -\beta-\beta^{-1}$ is a root of $x^3-x^2-2x+1$. Moreover $\beta^p = \beta$ (if $p\equiv 1 \bmod 7$) or $\beta^p = \beta^{-1}$ (if $p \equiv -1 \bmod 7)$. Either way $\alpha^p = \alpha$ so $\alpha \in \mathbb{F}_p$. For $p=7$ $$x^3-x^2-2x+1\equiv (x+2)^3 \pmod 7$$ as pointed out by @lhf in a comment.

Comment: Do you mind explaining why if $x^3 - x^2 - 2x + 1$ has a root in $\Bbb{F}_p$, then $\Bbb{F}_{p^2}$ contains a primitive seventh root of unity?

Comment: @ClementYung If $\alpha_1$, $\alpha_2$, $\alpha_3$ are the roots in $\mathbb{F}_p$ (as provided in the answer) then $$x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1 = \prod_{k=1}^3(x^2 + \alpha_k x + 1)$$

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't understand. The polynomial you gave contains all the primitive roots. What's next? And where does $\Bbb{F}_{p^2}$ comes in?

Comment: @ClementYung The right hand side is a product of quadratics over $\mathbb{F}_p$ so any root has degree $\leq 2$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$.

Comment: Why does the degree of the root matter here? Apologies but I'm afraid I'm completely lost. Do you mind explaining in more detail? I'm still relatively new to number theory.

Comment: In particular, I'm not sure how we can assure they the polynomial you mentioned has a root.

Comment: I have made a question on my queries [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3736057/why-does-the-polynomial-splitting-implies-existence-primitive-root-of-unity-in). If you are available, feel free to take a look.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, this is because the zeros of the polynomial is $-(\zeta^j+\zeta^{-j})$
for $\zeta=\exp(2\pi i/7)$ and $j\in\{1,2,3\}$. So it splits iff $\zeta+\zeta^{-1}\in\Bbb F_p$ for $\zeta$ now a primitive seventh root of unity
in an extension of $\Bbb F_p$. This is the case iff $(\zeta+\zeta^{-1})^p
=\zeta+\zeta^{-1}$ in characteristic $p$, and that is the case iff
$p\equiv\pm1\pmod7$.

Comment: There is no way that #\zeta+\zeta^{-1}\in\mathbb F_p$, because the $\zeta$ you define is a complex number. There are more careful ways to write this answer...

Comment: @ThomasAndrews There are more careful ways of writing comments too!

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown , feel free to give actual criticism, or perhaps use the name Lord Snark. What is wrong with my comment?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Its typesetting is somewhat suboptimal!